# How to get the Tuples in Java, if one of the Value is empty? IndexOutOfBound

Tags: java, list, tuples, indexoutofboundsexception, java-pair-rdd

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    List<Pair<String, String>> SubPartandMaster = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
        

    List<String> wtpmList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wtpmList.add("1");
    wtpmList.add("2");
    wtpmList.add("3");
    wtpmList.add("4");
    wtpmList.add("5");
   
    List<String> wtpList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wtpList.add("a");
    wtpList.add("b");
    wtpList.add("c");

    System.out.println(wtpmList);
    System.out.println(wtpList);
    for (int i = 0; i < wtpmList.size(); i++) {
        SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), wtpList.get(i)));
    }

    }
}
```

I know the second list doesn't have more values but I want to store `null` in that case.
For example

```
[(1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,null),(5,null)]
```

Instead of this, I get error

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[a, b, c]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
        at App.main(App.java:28)
```

I know the reason as I cannot retrieve more from wtpList as it has 3 elements.
But I can store null if the values are not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate over two list of different sizes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wtpmList.size(); i++) {
    SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), wtpList.get(i)));
}
```

one has five elements, the other three. This leads to `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`
as soon as `i=3`.

> I know the second list doesn't have more values but I want to store
> null in that case. For example

Assuming that wtpmList is always bigger then (or equal to) wtpList, you can simply iterate over the smallest list first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wtpList.size(); i++) {
    SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), wtpList.get(i)));
}
```

and add the nulls, after:

```
for (int i = wtpList.size(); i < wtpmList.size(); i++) {
    SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), null));
}
```

Not assuming anything about the list then you have to change your code to cover all the cases.

```
  int biggest_list = Math.max(wtpmList.size(), wtpList.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < biggest_list; i++) {
       if(i >= wtpmList.size())
          SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(null, wtpList.get(i)));
       else if (i >= wtpList.size())
          SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), null));
       else
          SubPartandMaster.add(new Pair<String, String>(wtpmList.get(i), wtpList.get(i)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override `get` so that it works like `poll` and return a null value if no element is present:

```
List<String> wtpList = new ArrayList<String>() {
  @Override
  public String get( int idx ) {
    return( idx < size() ? super.get( idx ) : null );
  }
};
```

Comment: An example code will be immensely helpful. If you can provide that.

Comment: You only have to substitute the definition of `wtpList` in Your program `List<String> wtpList = new ArrayList<String>();` with mine above and Your program should work correctly.